# How to automatically insert a value multiple times from another sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

In a source sheet I have values:

[image]

I want to insert `Apple` value from source sheet into a destination sheet multiple times. And I don't want to do it manually (sorry, Russian language excel, it might mean `=Sheet3!B2`):

[image]

If I select an `Apple` cell in a destination sheet and drag a mouse down with `Ctrl` pressed, Excel copies values from source sheet "as-is", which is not what I want:

[image]

How to duplicate only one specific value from source sheet into another sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write your cell as $B$2 it means the cell reference is absolute rather than relative. This means you can now copy/paste the cell with formula to any other cell and retain the link/formula. If you then edit Apple to Banana, it will be updated everywhere.

If you already made links, you can search/replace them all.

Comment: What is `$B$2`? How to get this value?

Comment: You've inserted: `=?????!B2` and you replace it with `=?????!$B$2` (russian replaced with ?) You basically add a $ before the B and before the 2. You could also do $B2 to make only the column fixed and the row not, or B$2 to make only the row fixed and the column not.